# Merging DataTables - disregarding the first row

Tags: c#, .net, merge, datatable

How can I merge DataTable objects ignoring the first row?

The datatable I need to merge with the one I've got comes from a parsed CSV file and its first row (sometimes) still contains headers, which are obviously not supposed to end up in the  resulting table...

**DataTable.Merge** method does not seem to offer such an option. What's the best way to do that? Just removing the first row beforehand? But that affects (alters) the "original", and what if I wanted it to stay as it was. Removing and reinserting after the merge? Smells like "clever coding". Is there really no better way?

Comment: Write a better parser...

Comment: I would if I had time for that

Comment: Just remove the first row then?

Comment: I will still need it (CSV headers are kept in the DataTable so that user can look them up in the DataGrid; DataGrid's headers are for something else). I can surely reinsert it, as I wrote in the question. I just thought there might be some other solution that's less of a hack.

Comment: The fact that you need the first row to (sometimes) have a different meaning than the other data in the DataTable also smells like "clever coding".

Comment: @C.Evenhuis - I agree, but that is something I just inherited. Personally I'd be happy to rewrite the app from scratch, but while I can't, I'm doing my best not to add new WTFs to the code :)

Comment: @Vibo - The simple solution is to merge both DataTables together then remove the entry you wish to remove before you use it.  This way you do not change the original DataTables only a copy of the original data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Editing my previous

I wrote code on similar lines and ended up with all rows of dt1 intact and dt2 containing only row 2 &3 of from dt1

```
var dt1 = new DataTable("Test");
dt1.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
dt1.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));

var dt2 = new DataTable("Test");
dt2.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
dt2.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));

dt1.Rows.Add(1, "Apple"); dt1.Rows.Add(2, "Oranges");
dt1.Rows.Add(3, "Grapes");
dt1.AcceptChanges();

dt1.Rows[0].Delete();
dt2.Merge(dt1);
dt2.AcceptChanges(); 
dt1.RejectChanges();
```

Let me know if you find it acceptable.

Vijay

Comment: In a `DataSet` - maybe, but when using `DataTable` on its own - `RejectChanges` does not restore a deleted row (I just tested it)...

Comment: Uhuh... yeah I actually think you're right! That's a nice one, and more concise/elegant - saving me the rewrite of the entire table. While C.Evenhuis's approach works, I'm switching to your answer as an accepted one, since it solves the problem with less coding.

Answer (score 1):

You could go through the rows separately and merge them into the table, something like

```
public static class DataTableExtensions
{
    public static void MergeRange(this DataTable dest, DataTable table, int startIndex, int length)
    {
        List<string> matchingColumns = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            // Only copy columns with the same name and type
            string columnName = table.Columns[i].ColumnName;
            if (dest.Columns.Contains(columnName))
            {
                if (dest.Columns[columnName].DataType == table.Columns[columnName].DataType)
                {
                    matchingColumns.Add(columnName);
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            int row = i + startIndex;
            DataRow destRow = dest.NewRow();
            foreach (string column in matchingColumns)
            {
                destRow[column] = table.Rows[row][column];
            }
            dest.Rows.Add(destRow);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the code, but won't it be a performance hit, rewriting it bit by bit like that (in case of large DataTables)? Or does "regular" Merge do the same thing internally, so it wouldn't make much difference...?

Comment: Internally `Merge` also loops through both rows and columns. It does alot more actually, for example I completely ignored the `RowState` property of the rows here. If you are curious (I was!) you can use ILSpy to see in plain C# code what happens internally.